# Combining conditions in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am using php and sql to check user information from the database. I need to check if the username and password is correct and the account is active. I have this sql query, but it does not work. What is the method to do it?

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE (name='foo' AND password='foo') AND active=1
```

Comment: Please be more specific than "it does not work."

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the query that i can see. even though removing those brackets will make it bit clean

Comment: @user1124076 What I mean is, what error are you getting, if any?

Comment: My query returns 0 row and I am sure that I have that fields in the database and typing the correct information. When I remove AND active=1 part, it works fine. Any ideas?

Comment: what is active when you print `SELECT * FROM foo WHERE (name='foo' AND password='foo')`... Also what is datatype of `active`??

Comment: what data type is your `active` field

Comment: if it is varchar, use `active='1'`... This will solve your problem...

Comment: active field is int type

Comment: ok, what do you get under `active` field when you execute query `SELECT * FROM foo WHERE name='foo' AND password='foo'`

Comment: I believe you must be having `active = 0` hence you are not getting any row for query `SELECT * FROM foo WHERE name='foo' AND password='foo' AND active = 1`

Comment: @user1124076 : Will you mind replying???

Comment: It was an issue with the php code I used for hashing passwords... Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could debug your sql like this in php:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM foo WHERE (name='foo' AND password='foo') AND active=1";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
```

This "or die (mysql_error())" will give you the exact error of that query, maybe the DB isn't selected if that happened use mysql?query($sql, $db)...

Hope it helps

Answer (score 4):

for me

```
 SELECT * FROM foo WHERE (name="foo" AND password="foo") AND active=1
```

should be same as

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE name="foo" AND password="foo" AND active=1
```

the above query assumes that field `active` is of family type `int` In case its varchar or char you r query should be like this

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE name="foo" AND password="foo" AND active='1'
```

and the query should work and i assume you are taking care of SQL injections from php

Answer (score 2):

Where you say, "When I remove AND active=1 part, it works fine. Any ideas?"

Try changing it to AND active<>1 to see if the issue lies in that field. It's possible 'active' may be null or some other value. Try outputting the value (try var_dump($var) in PHP) to see what is returned for the 'active' field. If the value is 0, a blanck string, or null, then you've isolated your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The query looks correct (assuming columns name, password, and active exist in table foo), but if you're using it in PHP you might be running into trouble with the double quotes if they're inside a string you're declaring.  You might need to escape them or use single quotes.

Comment: And the meaning of single / double quote can be different, especially in other SQL languages.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, use `mysql_real_escape_string()` or a PDO method to escape your input. You do not want people messing around in your database.

A simplified version of what I normally do is

```
SELECT main.id,
       main.isActive,
       (SELECT count(sub.id) 
               FROM users AS sub
               WHERE sub.id = main.id
               AND   sub.credential = 'md5password'
               LIMIT 1
               ) AS credentialMatches
        FROM   users AS main
        WHERE  main.identity = 'username'
```

Grab your result:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$data   = array();
if (false !== $result) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
}
```

Handle your result:

```
if (count($data) < 1) {
    // username not found
} else if (count($data) > 1) {
    // multiple rows with the same username, bad thing
} else {
    $row = $data[0]

    if (false === (boolean) $row['isActive']) {
        // user not active
    } else if (true === (boolean) $row['credentialMatches']) {
        // SUCCESS
        // valid user and credential
    }
}
```

Also note: ALWAYS store password at least as an MD5 hash like so `WHERE credential = MD5('password')`. Same when you are inserting: `SET credential = MD5('password')`. This way, when someone else will ever read you database, user passwords won't be revealed so easily.

An even better is to add an additional salt to hash, but that might be going to far for now.

Comment: escaping inputs has nothing to do with safety.

Comment: DUDE, ever heard of sql injection? WTF.

Comment: yes. a little. and, from that I know, escaping has nothing to do with it.

Comment: I understand he's using strings in his example. But judging from his question I think he does not have a lot of experience doing this kind of thing. If that is the case, I'm just trying to give him some extra knowledge, or at least send him down the right path. If he does know, then all I've done is some extra typing.

Comment: @Shrapnel Are you trolling??? Let's say we have this query: `"SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='{$_POST['username']}' AND password='{$_POST['password']}'"` and someone posts the following data: `username: aidan` and `password: ' OR ''='` - What do you think would happen?

Comment: this is not an "extra knowledge" but rather a disservice. Followed literally, "escaping inputs" will make his code actually vulnerable to injection. Either give him full info (if you want to share some "extra knowledge" ) or leave the matter alone.

Comment: Let's say we have this query: `"SELECT * FROM users WHERE active=$_POST['active']"`. What will your precious escaping do?

Comment: Fair point about full info or none at all. Same goes for your first comment. At least I'm trying to write something constructive. Lets not argue any further. Good day to you.

Comment: I have fixed the issue, and yes I am salting passwords and sanitizing all inputs. Thanks for your comments and answers :)

Answer (score 1):

> My query returns 0 row and I am sure that I have that fields in the database and typing the correct information. When I remove AND active=1 part, it works fine. Any ideas?

Yes. 
The idea is very simple. Just check if a record with name='foo' and password='foo' has active=1. Then correct mistake and your data

Hint: a programmer cannot be *sure* when **the logic** says he is wrong.

Comment: Seemed pretty straightforward to me.